# hide all rows with td containing value from drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

iam trying to hide all rows in table except for the ones with `<td>` containing same text as user selected from dropdown. thought it should be easy but im struggling with it for long now...i tried something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name=selectName]').change(function() {
        $("td").each(function(index, paragraph) {
            $td = $(paragraph);
            if ($td.html() === $('select[name=selectName]').val()) {
                //hide the matched row rather than remove it
                $(not(this)).parent("tr:first").hide();
            }
        });
        $('select[name="selectName"]').on('change', function() {
            $("tr").show();
        });
    });
});
```

but it didnt work so i tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name=selectedName]').change(function() {
        $('tr').filter(function () {
            return $(this).find('td').filter(function () {
                return $(this).text().indexOf('$('select[name=select2]').val()') == -1;
            }).length;
        }).$(this).parent("tr:first").hide();
    });
});
```

but didnt work as well...this is how i build my dropdown:

```
$query = "SELECT user_name FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($query); ?>
<select name="selectedName" id="userSelected">
    <option value="" disabled selected>user name</option>
    <?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $line['user_name'];?>">
            <?php echo $line['user_name'];?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

any help to lead for solution?? thanks

Comment: How's this question different from your last two?

Comment: This question does not have the details needed to answer.

Comment: What does your table look like?

Answer (score 0):

Knowing you have not posted enough info for us to help you finish, I can at least point out an error in your code.

You should use the F12 tools so you can spot these errors.

Depending on the browser you are using, the Console area of the F12 tools will show `ReferenceError: not is not defined`.

Clicking the line number will show that the error is

`$(not(this)).parent("tr:first").hide();`

(unless there's another error before this in which case you need to fix that first)

So `not(this)` is not valid syntax. If you don't understand why, please post a separate question, more specific, and we would be happy to explain the meaning of these things.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to filter to rows *containing* the text in a given value, or rows whose *entire html is equal to* the text in the given value? This is an important difference, an I assume you mean the former since that's the wording you use, but your code seems to do the latter.

Also keep in mind that `$(element).html()` will give you a very different string from `$(element).text()`. In the following example, `$('.bunny').text()` will include the string "I am a bunny" but `$('.bunny').html()` won't.

```
<div class="bunny">
  Hi! I am a <strong>bunny</strong>.
</div>
```

If you're looking to filter rows by their *text contents*, I'd do something like the following:

```
var search_term = $(this).val();

var matching_rows $('tr').filter(function(){
  var this_row_text = $(this).text();
  // Standardize whitespace (in case it's useful)
  this_row_text = this_row_text.replace(/\s+/g, " ");

  if (this_row_text.indexOf(search_term) > -1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});

matching_rows.addClass("highlighted"); // or whatever
```

Note that I created lots of variables at each step; even if the var is only used once, this can lead to much more descriptive and readable code that's less of a pain for you to troubleshoot and maintain later on. When my JS code is misbehaving, the first thing I do is I go in and break out variables like this. The resulting JS is about twice as many lines, but I almost always spot and fix multiple issues just by going through that process. Jquery makes it too easy to write overly dense code. ;-)

On a more general note, I think I spot a number of Jquery errors in your code snippets above. We could point those out individually for you, but that's not what SO is here for; focus on breaking your problem down into smaller and smaller pieces so you can tackle those errors one at a time, rather than being stumped by several of them acting up at once. For example, if you're trying to troubleshoot the filtering behavior, open up Chrome's dev tools and just start playing with filters in the JS console. Then once you're confident with that, you can copy & paste back into your IDE and be confident that "OK, I know these 3 lines are working as intended".

Answer (score 0):

First set up some constants for the bits of the page that aren't going to change (this will help speed up your code):

```
var select = $('#userSelected');
var trs    = $('tr');
```

Then in your change function you just need to test the text in each row against the value and toggle whether the the row is hidden or not:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var select = $('#userSelected');
    var trs    = $('tr');
    select.change( function() {
        var value = select.val();
        trs.each(function(){
            var isShown = $( 'td:first', this ).text() == value;
            $(this).toggle( isShown );
        });
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d4ga7a88/)